# Assigning part of a formula as a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a part of a formula to a variable. I have this formula:

```
=ROUND(N8-N8*85%,5)
```

I want that my variable assumes the value of 85%. My ultimate goal is to change the percentage so I receive other results. My aim is to change the percentage until I receive the results.

Comment: It would really help if you could describe how you plan to 'change the percentage'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to come up with your own way of varying `seekValue`, but the following would put the formula in cell A1..

```
Dim seekValue As Long

seekValue = 85

Range("A1").formula = "=ROUND(N8-N8*" & CStr(seekValue) & "%,5)"
```

Comment: You don't need the `CStr`, vba will automatically cast an integer to a string

Comment: I guess.. I just figured using a value rather than a string makes it easier to vary. Didn't know that about casting automatically though, good tip!

Comment: Personally I always try to use explicit casting rather than implicit - I find it less error-prone and easier to read - but its just a style thing.

Answer (score 1):

Build it up using a string:

```
dim perc as string
perc = "85"

dim formula as string 'assuming formula is not a reserved keyword, just check that first
formula = "=ROUND(N8-N8*" & perc & "%,5)"
```

Or if you were varying this in a loop

```
For perc = 10 To 100 Step 10
    formula = "=ROUND(N8-N8*" & perc & "%,5)"
Next perc
```

Comment: This would not help, because 85 is not fixed. My goal is to change it so I receive other desirable results. My aim is to change the percentage until I receive the results.

Comment: yeah... and `perc` is a variable that you can vary?

Comment: @tombata maybe you should describe your problem fully. It sounds to me like it's possible that you shouldn't be using VBA but rather use the solver add-in

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you, as long as you have varied perc values:

```
Sub stack()
    Dim perc As Integer
    Dim formula As String
    perc = InputBox("Enter Percentage value")
    formula = "ROUND(N8-N8*" & perc & "%" & ",5)"
End Sub
```